# "How do I" vs "How to"

Tags: discussion

I've seen [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/60/how-do-i-fill-a-hot-water-urn-when-it-doesnt-fit-in-the-sink?noredirect=1#comment125_60) have a "how to" title. I edited it, and then the asker said the system said the title was "too subjective". Can we change it so that the system doesn't think it's "too subjective"?

Answer (score 5):

Please avoid trivial edits like this.

You might have a stylistic preference for "How do I foo the bar" as opposed to "How to foo the bar" (or sometimes even just "Fooing the bar"). However, neither is actually incorrect in the context of Stack Exchange question titles. Additionally, without other changes being made to the post such an edit is thoroughly trivial.

From [the help center](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage. Please be mindful of this and make your edits count, so that the new attention is brought to something substantial.

Further reading [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82895/165581) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82873/165581).

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56625/how-to-vs-how-do-i

Comment: @Quy I updated my answer to say that I'm talking about correctness in the context of Stack Exchange titles. This community is welcome to require complete sentences in titles, but you'll have to decide that as a community. There's no rule for it right now, and as such the "How to X" syntax is perfectly legitimate. No need for the edits.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a legitimate edit or not, the system still shouldn't say the title is "subjective".

Comment: So it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to [abby's answer](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23/59), I'd like to post my own.

I've been thinking about this a little bit, and have concluded that it's really fine.

Here's why: the reminder to remove mentions of person ("me," "you" and "I") from question titles will act as a reminder to people not to ask subjective ("What do you think I should do?") or polling ("What do you think is the best...?") questions.

It can be annoying to have to reword question titles, but I think that's a fair price to pay if it minimizes low-quality questions.